# How to keep my application reads input even though it is not active?

Tags: c#, .net, xna

I want to learn how to implement my application **X** keeps on reading input from my gamepad or from any input devices, even though application **Y** is the active window. This application **X** is like a WarcraftIII Hotkey that's only reads input when WarcraftIII or application **Y** is the active window.

Comment: By default XNA does just that. Normally you check if the game's window is active to disable stray input, but in your case I don't know what to offer. Maybe you're already blocking input updates when the game window is inactive? You should post some of your input update method code.

Comment: Actually, I referenced XNA to this window form application. I also add backgroundworker to check for any inputs and to report those inputs to application **X**

Comment: If you're doing WinForms-XNA hybrid and you just want an XNA game, I don't think you're doing it right. Plain and simple XNA game should not have your input problem.

Answer (score 0):

You must use Windows API to add a keyboard hook, monitor the keyboard input

Answer (score 0):

you basically need a keylogger.  most people would do a global hook.  read up on global hooks.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/558413/Minimal-Key-Logger-using-RAWINPUT

the link is actually full c# source code and explanation for another way to do it.  Have some patience, read it, then read up on operating system "hooks" eg, global hooks.  You'll feel like a much more powerful programmer after that. And you'll know your options a be able to do this.